# Error-page not working (with pic)

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I'm working in Eclipse+tomcat. My custom made static error page is not showing up in tomcat when i click on url for non-existing pages. generated-error.html has a simple img src="404_man.jpg" tag. But I keep getting the error page shown on the pic. 
[image]

My servlet version is 3.0 if i view it from manifest.mf.

Comment: have you defined your error page in web.xml ??

Comment: yeah i did, i showed the web.xml in the first picture, do you see pictures?

Comment: nope... pictures are not displaying yet

Comment: okay. now? i re uploaded the pics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the error definition for generic errors, not just 404.

/general-error.html

And are you sure tomcat is running on port 8080?
The error page does not look like Tomcat7's default 'cant find page' page.

Comment: yep i tried that. double-clicking on server tells me that http port is 8080. apache's default error page with huge letters show up when i completely delete the error-page lines from web.xml

Comment: the only thing I can see is the the error page has a '/' at the start, but the index.html entry does not. hmm

Comment: it seems to be a browser issue, when i test with external web browser i see my custom error page, but internal web browser always display this generic error page.

Answer (score 0):

Some browser like IE needs atleast 512 bytes of data to render. Otherwise it will not render the response. Try adding more content in your error page.

I believe you have very less content in your error page.

Mozilla will work without any problem in this kind of situation.